# как такой код ES6 выглядел бы в классическом JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

В этой части кода React есть стрелочные функции(ES2015), я о них почитал, но так как полгода учил классический JS то лучше воспринимаются обычные функции. Помогите этот код перевести в обычние функции, в классический JS.Без объяснений что делает данный код, просто перевести

```
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/products').then(res => res.json())
      .catch(err => fetch('db.json').then(res => res.json()).then(data => data.products))
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ products: data });
        this.listProducts();
      });
  }

handleRemoveFromCart = (e, product) => {
    this.setState(state => {
      const cartItems = state.cartItems.filter(a => a.id !== product.id);
      localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(cartItems));
      return { cartItems: cartItems };
    })
  }
```

Comment: https://babeljs.io/en/repl

Comment: А в чем собственно говоря сложность? Вместо function (req, res) {} , можно записать (req, res) => {}. Там и изучать то толком нечего, удобнее и проще. Плюс в стрелочной функции область видимости переменной this не теряется, по сравнению с обычной функцией.

Comment: @MoloF, может его then пугает